# How can I play diablo 3 on playonlinux? Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL

Tags: games, opengl, playonlinux

I have recently encountered a huge problem when installing diablo 3 on playonlinux (PoL). The game launch menu started but when I click on the play button the window close immediately and there is just  diablo iii.exe process running in background.

The debugging console of playonlinux showed during the process:

Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.

I suspect that the 32bit nvidia openGL lib is not installed or loaded. My first question is how do I install the nvidia-glx package without gettng the following error?

```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Package nvidia-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
   is only available from another source

   E: Package 'nvidia-glx' has no installation candidate
```

currently, I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise) using quadro 2000m with the latest Nvidia driver 310.19 installed (thinkpad w520). I am pretty sure i have installed opengl 32bit libraries during the driver installation in recovery mode, but somehow this still doesn't work.

Following is the xorg.conf file generated by the nvidia-xconfig. Is this configuration correct or do I need to modify it to load glx module?

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 310.19  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-             08.nvidia.com)  Thu Nov  8 02:09:12 PST 2012


Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Unknown"
HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Any suggestion and help to solve this problem is much appreciated.